# Fill a field with a dynamic name in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, global-variables, casperjs

I can succesfully logged in a website and then fill a form and get the results.
Now im trying to do this for anyone who uses my app. The problem is that the form I have to fill has a field name that changes to the number of user.

like this:

```
casper.thenOpen('http://www.foo.com/index.html', function() {
    this.fill('form[action="/cgi-bin/login.cgi"]', { login: user,password:pass }, true);
    this.click('input[type="submit"][name="enter"]');
    this.wait(5000,function(){
        this.capture('eff_ss2.png');
    });
});
```

Everything is fine untill here (I read the login and pass with `casper.cli.raw.get();`
and then I do this:

```
this.fill('form[action="../foo.cgi"]', { 
    'from_city':            ori,
    'to_city':          dest,
    'plan_03231':       'whatev',
    'aspp_03231':       'whatev'
}, true);
```

The `03231` will change according to the user who logged in. How can I do this dynamically? I already tried to make:

```
var plan = 'plan_0'+user;
var obj{}
obj[plan] = 'whatev'

this.fill('form[action="../foo.cgi"]', { 
    'from_city':            ori,
    'to_city':          dest,
    obj,
    'aspp_03231':       'whatev'
}, true);
```

but is not working. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last snippet you have the id of the user in the `user` variable, but put an object into an object item place. This is not valid JavaScript. Since the object key is a composite, you need to set it using `obj[''+id] = '';` syntax:

```
var obj = { 
    'from_city':  ori,
    'to_city':    dest
};

obj['plan_0'+user] = 'whatev';
obj['aspp_0'+user] = 'whatev';

this.fill('form[action="../foo.cgi"]', obj, true);
```

An easier method where you don't need the explicit user id is simply selecting the form fields based on the beginning of the name attribute using the [`^=` attribute matcher](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/#rel-begins) and [`casper.fillSelectors`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillselectors):

```
this.fillSelectors('form[action="../foo.cgi"]', { 
    '*[name="from_city"]': ori,
    '*[name="to_city"]':   dest,
    '*[name^="plan_0"]':   'whatev'
    '*[name^="aspp_0"]':   'whatev'
}, true);
```